# Как сделать поиск по статичному сайту?

Tags: php, jquery

Есть статичный старый сайт, с кучами страниц сделанных на html. Вопрос в том как реализовать более менее быстрый поиск? В какую сторону смотреть? Так же сделал на php скрипт который просто ищет текст в файлах но работает ооочень медленно, мб есть какие то способы индексации страниц или что вроде того.

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 900);

if(!isset($_GET['s'])) {
    die('You must define a search term!');
}

$search_in = array('html', 'htm');
$search_dir = '.';
$countWords = 15;

$files = list_files($search_dir);
$search_results = array();
foreach($files as $file){
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    preg_match_all("/\<p\>(.*)".$_GET['s']."(.*)\<\/p\>/i", $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach($matches as $match){
        $match[1] = trim_result($match[1]);
        $match[2] = trim_result($match[2], true);
        $match[1] .= '<span style="background: #ffff00;">';
        $match[2] = '</span>'.$match[2];

        preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/", $contents, $matches2);
        $search_results[] = array($file, $match[1].$_GET['s'].$match[2], $matches2[1]);
    }
}

?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Search results</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php foreach($search_results as $result) :?>
        <div>
            <h3><a href="<?php echo $result[0]; ?>"><?php echo $result[2]; ?></a></h3>
            <p><?php echo $result[1]; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
    </html>

<?php
function list_files($dir){
    global $search_in;

    $result = array();
    if(is_dir($dir)){
        if($dh = opendir($dir)){
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if(!($file == '.' || $file == '..')){
                    $file = $dir.'/'.$file;
                    if(is_dir($file) && $file != './.' && $file != './..'){
                        $result = array_merge($result, list_files($file));
                    }
                    else if(!is_dir($file)){
                        if(in_array(get_file_extension($file), $search_in)){
                            $result[] = $file;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

function get_file_extension($filename){
    $result = '';
    $parts = explode('.', $filename);
    if(is_array($parts) && count($parts) > 1){
        $result = end($parts);
    }
    return $result;
}

function trim_result($text, $start = false){
    $words = split(' ', strip_tags($text));
    if($start){
        $words = array_slice($words, 0, $countWords);
    }
    else{
        $start = count($words) - $countWords;
        $words = array_slice($words, ($start < 0 ? 0 : $start), $countWords);
    }
    return implode(' ', $words);
}

?>
```

Comment: Заносите содержимое страниц в ElasticSearch и ищите с помощью него.

Comment: @Oboroten не по теме конечно но сомневаюсь, что если статичные html то есть ElasticSearch :)

Comment: А  по теме что вы хотите искать по сайту конкретно, фразы на страницах, названия страниц, сколько страниц на сайте примерно. Да и не плохо было бы скрипт выложить.

Comment: @Sergalas. Заголовки, фразы страниц ~50-60. Находил еще http://www.tipue.com/search/ не знаю, каждый раз вносить и туда и туда не удобно. Да и это курсовая работа) просят сделать на стороне клиента еще, я в ступоре уже неделю.

Comment: То есть использование баз данных не приветствуется?

Comment: @Sergalas именно, если бы можно было бы использовать бд то и вопрос бы отпал :)

Comment: единственное что приходит на ум очистить $contents перед foreach ну хоть как то ускорить процесс

Comment: @Evand а нельзя ли написать скрипт, который занесет все в БД, если такое решение принимается, то попробуйте)

Comment: @SonicMyst, хорошо что мне пришло оповещение на почту, старый вопрос же) хотя до сих пор не решил до конца) вообщем сделал сам поиск на js в реакте(хз почему, понравился)и не могу нормально написать парсер на php что бы он формировал просто Json файлик с данными, по сути та же бд только в профиль) не получается парсер сделать потому что там php4, все библиотеки либо кривые, либо просто не скачать)

Answer (score 1):

По сути, для быстрого поиска нужно проиндексировать содержимое. У меня есть сайт с очень похожим случаем, расскажу о своем опыте.

Быстрый поиск я делал в связке со [Сфинксом](http://sphinxsearch.com/), поиск работает очень быстро, с учетом морфологии и выводом сниппетов.

Идея такая:

- получаем содержимое страниц
- скармливаем Сфинксу по расписанию
- создаем отдельную страницу поиска

## Получаем содержимое страниц

Все страницы нужно обойти и сформировать XML-документ, который нужно подать на вход Сфинкса для индексации.

Создаем файл `/var/www/site.ru/xmlpipe2.php`:

```php
class MakeSearch {

  const
    // адрес сайта
    SITE_BASE = 'http://site.ru'
    ;

  public function run()
  {
    try {
      $this->startXml();
      $this->putXmlSchema();

      // Главная
      $this->addPage('/', self::SITE_BASE . 'index.html');

      /*
        ... тут - другие страницы, можно найти файлы через
          foreach (glob('/var/www/site.ru/public/*.php') as $file) {}
        и "преобразовать" в URI
      */

      $this->endXml();
      fwrite(STDOUT, $this->xml->flush(true)); // против переполнения памяти
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      $msg = $e->getMessage();
      fwrite(STDERR, $msg);
      die(1);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Добавление страницы в XML
   */

  protected function addPage($loc)
  {
    $uri = self::SITE_BASE . $loc;
    $content = file_get_contents($uri);

    /*
      Тут нужно:
      - очистить содержимое $content от лишнего - скриптов, шапки, футера, и т.п.
      - найти заголовок H1 или Title
      Можно использовать регулярки и \DOMDocument
      На выходе должна получиться пригодная для индексирования структура $doc:
    */

    $doc = [
      "text" => "Текст страницы с HTML-оформлением, Сфинкс понимает его",
      "title" => "Заголовок",
      "uri" => $uri
    ];

    $this->putXmlDoc($doc);
    unset($doc); // против утечки памяти если $doc - объект
    fwrite(STDOUT, $this->xml->flush(true)); // против переполнения памяти
  }

  protected $xml;
  protected function startXml()
  {
    $this->xml = new XmlWriter();

    $this->xml->openMemory();
    $this->xml->setIndent(true);
    $this->xml->setIndentString('  ');
    $this->xml->startDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

      $this->xml->startElement('sphinx:docset');
  }

  protected function putXmlSchema()
  {
    $this->xml->startElement('sphinx:schema');

      // основной текст - для поиска
      $this->xml->startElement('sphinx:field');
      $this->xml->writeAttribute('name', 'text');
      $this->xml->endElement();

      // основной текст - для сниппетов
      $this->xml->startElement('sphinx:attr');
      $this->xml->writeAttribute('name', 'snippet');
      $this->xml->writeAttribute('type', 'string');
      $this->xml->endElement();

      // заголовок
      $this->xml->startElement('sphinx:attr');
      $this->xml->writeAttribute('name', 'title');
      $this->xml->writeAttribute('type', 'string');
      $this->xml->endElement();

      // URI
      $this->xml->startElement('sphinx:attr');
      $this->xml->writeAttribute('name', 'uri');
      $this->xml->writeAttribute('type', 'string');
      $this->xml->endElement();

    $this->xml->endElement();
  }

  protected $docID = 0;
  protected function putXmlDoc(array $doc)
  {
    $this->docID++;
    $this->xml->startElement('sphinx:document');
    $this->xml->writeAttribute('id', $this->docID);

      $this->xml->startElement('text');
        $this->xml->writeCData($doc['text']);
      $this->xml->endElement();

      $this->xml->startElement('snippet');
        $this->xml->writeCData($doc['text']);
      $this->xml->endElement();

      $this->xml->startElement('title');
        $this->xml->writeCData($doc['title']);
      $this->xml->endElement();

      $this->xml->startElement('uri');
        $this->xml->writeCData($doc['uri']);
      $this->xml->endElement();

    $this->xml->endElement();
  }

  protected function endXml()
  {
    $this->xml->endElement();
  }

  protected function stderr($msg)
  {
    fwrite(STDERR, $msg . PHP_EOL);
  }

}

$MakeSearch = new MakeSearch;
$MakeSearch->run();
```

Этот скрипт выдает примерно такой документ, который можно передавать в Сфинкс:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sphinx:docset>
  <sphinx:schema>
    <sphinx:field name="text"/>
    <sphinx:attr name="snippet" type="string"/>
    <sphinx:attr name="title" type="string"/>
    <sphinx:attr name="uri" type="string"/>
  </sphinx:schema>
  <sphinx:document id="1">
    <text><![CDATA[Текст страницы с HTML-оформлением, Сфинкс понимает его]]></text>
    <snippet><![CDATA[Текст страницы с HTML-оформлением, Сфинкс понимает его]]></snippet>
    <title><![CDATA[Заголовок]]></title>
    <uri><![CDATA[http://site.ru/]]></uri>
  </sphinx:document>
</sphinx:docset>
```

## Скармливаем Сфинксу по расписанию

Предварительно необходимо установить Сфинкс.

Строка для крона с целью индексирования каждые 12 часов выглядит так:

```
* */12 * * * indexer --rotate site_content > /tmp/sphinx-site.ru 2>&1
```

Теперь нужно определить индекс `site_content`, для чего в конец `/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf` добавить:

```
# Источник данных - наш PHP скрипт
source site_content_src
{
  type = xmlpipe2
  xmlpipe_command = php /var/www/site.ru/xmlpipe2.php
}

# Собственно, индекс
index site_content
{
  source = site_content_src
  path = /var/data/sphinx/site_
  docinfo = extern
  morphology = stem_ru
  min_stemming_len = 3
  min_word_len = 2
  min_infix_len = 2
  charset_table = /, 0..9, A..Z->a..z, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, U+401->U+435, U+451->U+435
  html_strip = 1
  # wordforms = /
  # stopwords = /
  blend_chars = -
}
```

По опциям можно прочитать в спраке. Некоторые из них могут устареть в новых версиях (кажется, `charset_table`).

Первый раз можно запустить индексацию вручную из командной строки:

```
indexer --rotate site_content
```

## Создаем отдельную страницу поиска

Сфинкс может работать по протоколу MySQL на 9306 и общаться на "урезанном" SQL. Для поиска используется `WHERE MATCH("то, что ищем")`, а для сниппетов - `CALL SNIPPETS(...)`.

Вот класс для поиска:

```php
class SphinxSearch {

  public function __construct()
  {
    $dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;port=%s', '127.0.0.1', 9306);
    $this->mysql = new PDO($dsn, $this->config['mysql']['login'], $this->config['mysql']['password'],
      [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
      ]
    );
  }

  public function get($q)
  {
    $db = $this->mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM site_content WHERE MATCH(:q)", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
    $db->execute([':q' => $q]);
    $list = $db->fetchAll();

    if(count($list) > 0) {
      $db = $this->mysql->prepare("CALL SNIPPETS(:snippet, 'site_content', :q)", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));

      foreach($list as &$it) {
        $db->execute([':snippet' => $it['snippet'], ':q' => $q]);
        $it['snippet'] = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
        unset($it['id']);
      }
    }

    return $list;
  }

}
```

Использование очень простое:

```php
$sphinxSearch = new SphinxSearch;
$data = $sphinxSearch->get($_GET['q']);
```

Comment: блин, некропостингом занялся

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать кастомный поиск по сайту от гугла. Не уверен, зависит ли база поиска от текущего индекса сайта, но как вариант стоит рассмотреть.
Больше информации в *[документации](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2717638?hl=ru)*

Comment: вряд ли платный гугло-поиск пойдет на курсовую работу, как у автора :)

Comment: @teran так вроде до 500,000 запросов фри тариф?

Comment: может и так. в первом абзаце по вашей ссылке  просто написано что решение платное.

Comment: @teran, да, хотя изначально думал, что это бесплатно, т.к. часто видел на малопопулярных блогах, которые вряд ли вкладывались в оплату этой услуги) Но, насколько понимаю, в такой выдаче больше фишек, нежели в обычно поиске по 'site:siteurl.com'